# C# String Property and string literal concatenation issue

Tags: c#

I am a bit new at C# and I have run into a string concatenation issue. I am hoping someone might be able to give me a hint and help me resolve this. I have searched Google extensively and have spent more than a week on this so any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

I have created a custom PathEditor for a string property. The property basically allows the user to key in a file to use in the app. If the file typed in is correct, it shows in the property cell as it should. What I am trying to do is output to the property cell an error message if the file typed in does not exist - I check this in my file validator. Here is the string literal issue.

If I use:

```
return inputFile+"Error_";
```

this works OK and I get the outpur file123.txtError_ in the property grid cell.

If I use:

```
return "Error_"+inputFile;
```

I get only the inputFile without the literal "Error_". Sot he property grid cell shows file123.txt in the property grid cell.

I have checked and inputFile is a string type. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Also, is there any way to change to font, and/or, color of the message output? I tried to change the background of the property grid cell and I understand that this is not possible to do.

Thank you.
Z

More of the code:

```
[
Description("Enter or select the wave file. If no extension, or a non .wav extension, is specified, the default extension .wav will be added to the filename."),
GridCategory("Sound"),
Gui.Design.DisplayName ("Input Sound"),
PathEditor.OfdParamsAttribute("Wave files (*.wav)|*.wav", "Select Audio File"),
Editor(typeof(PathEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))
]
public string InputWavefile
{
    get { return System.IO.Path.GetFileName(inputtWavefile); }
    set 
    {
        if (value != inputWavefile)  // inputWavefile has been changed
        {                           
            // validate the input stringg
             _inputWavefile = FileValidation.ValidateFile(value);

            // assign validated value
            inputWavefile = _inputWavefile;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some more code would be appreciated. Looking at what I see know, seems impossible. Except one thing that could be cause of the problem: your Grid cell formatting. No idea what grid is it, but usually Grids have formatted cells :)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am referring here to the standard Propertygrid. I have the dfollowing property

Comment: To what type binded that cell in ProperyGrid?

Comment: @Zeos6, Is it a mneumonic issue?  The `_` character might be causing the character after the `_` to be underlined (and treated as a hotkey).  Is there anything funny going on like that?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I removed the _ character and still no go. This is really stumping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your filename looks something like this, ***C:\Folder\FileName.txt*** when you start out.

In your FileValidation.ValidateFile() method you

```
return "Error_" + InputFileName;
```

it now looks like this: **Error_C:\Folder\FileName.txt**.
So, when you run the line below,

```
get { return System.IO.Path.GetFileName( _inputWavefile ); }
```

it strips off the path and returns the filename only, ***FileName.txt***.

Even when the filename is not valid, you are still running System.IO.Path.GetFileName() on it.

Comment: You are correct in what you say here. I think you maybe onto something here. I think this may be it. How might I get around this. I still want to show InputFile.txt without the full path info but if the file does not exist I want to show Error_C:\Folder\InputFile.txt.

Comment: Move the validation out of the InputWavefile setter. Then call FileValidation.ValidateFile(InputWavefile); when you need to do validation.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying that now.

Comment: The issue was the getter stripping the ERROR_ part. I reworked the getter and the setter and it works great now. Thanks very much all you folks! Very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

My *guess* is that you've got a funky character at the start of `inputFile` which is confusing things - try looking at it in the debugger using `inputFile.ToCharArray()` to get an array of characters.

The string concatenation itself should be fine - it's how the value is being interpreted which is the problem, I suspect...

Comment: I tried your suggestion of inputFile.ToCharArray and I got no characters. The output was System.Char[] and nothing after that yet the inputFile exists.

Comment: Zeos6: I didn't say to *print* `inputFile.ToCharArray()` - just examine it in the debugger.

Comment: You are right...I should not have printed it. I will examine in debugger. Thanks for pointing it out to me. I messed that. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a `PropertyGrid` in winforms app. Then it's neither a string concatenation issue, nor `PropertyGrid` issue, as could be proven by the following snippet. So you need to look elsewhere in your code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    PropertyGrid pg;
    public Form1() {
        pg = new PropertyGrid();
        pg.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(pg);

        var inputFile = "some fileName.txt";
        var obj = new Obj();
        obj.One = "Error_" + inputFile;
        obj.Two = inputFile + "Error_";
        pg.SelectedObject = obj;
    }
}


class Obj {
    public string One { get; set; }
    public string Two { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I understand your point. The weird thin is that string2+string1 works and string1+string2 does not - in my case. I will look at my file validation.